# Solving $ \sqrt{x - 4} + \sqrt{x - 7} = 1 $.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

I have the equation $ \sqrt{x - 4} + \sqrt{x - 7} = 1 $.

I tried to square both sides, but then I got a more difficult equation:
$$
2 x - 11 + 2 \sqrt{x^{2} - 11 x - 28} = 1.
$$
Can someone tell me what I should do next?

Comment: Get everything but the root to the other side and square again.

Comment: Putting 8 in the first equation, this leads you to 3=1, check the answers before accepting one.

Comment: Note that squaring an equation like this can give spurious solutions, because squaring loses information about signs. So the putative solution identified below i.e. $x=8$ which doesn't work, is a solution of the related equation $\sqrt{x-4}-\sqrt {x-7}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

squaring gives
$$x-4+x-7+2\sqrt{x-4}\sqrt{x-7}=1$$
$$\sqrt{x-4}\sqrt{x-7}=12-2x$$
$$(x-4)(x-7)=36+x^2-12x$$
$$x=8$$
but $8$ fulfills not our equation.

Comment: Of course, you have to check if this is a solution, which it isn't.

Comment: i have checked it

Comment: Try to put $8$ in the first equation, this leads you to $3=1$ which is clearly false!

Answer (score 11):

There is no real solution since you need $x \geq 7$ for sure. The left hand side is an increasing function for $x \geq 7$ and so it's minimum is $\sqrt{3}>1$.

Comment: +1: A solution of supreme elegance without any hard calculations.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $x$ is a solution. Flip things over. We get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-4}+\sqrt{x-7}}=1.$$
Rationalizing the denominator, and minor manipulation gives
$$\sqrt{x-4}-\sqrt{x-7}=3.$$
From this, addition gives $2\sqrt{x-4}=4$. The only possibility is $x=8$, which is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x-4}+\sqrt{x-7}=1<=>$$
$$-11+2\sqrt{(x-7)(x-4)}=12-2x<=>$$
$$4(x-7)(x-4)=(12-2x)^2<=>$$
$$4x^2-44x+112=4x^2-48x+144<=>$$
$$4x-32=0<=>$$
$$4(x-8)=0<=>$$
$$x-8=0<=>$$
$$x=8$$

BUT THIS SOLUTION IS INCORRECT SO THERE ARE NO SOLUTIONS!!!!!

Comment: If this solution is incorrect, you shouldn't use equivalence arrows in each step!

Comment: When you square both sides, you use implication arrows, not iff, unless you add some additional inequality constraints for $x$. Squaring is not an invertible operation unless with some additional inequality constraints. And indeed $8$ is not a solution, so you can't have iff arrows everywhere.

Comment: My math professor on the university told us that we have to use them to give the relationship between the equations, so here in Holland we use them as I did

Comment: @JanEerland Algebraic manipulations often result in equivalent expressions. But not in the case of squaring both sides. E.g., we cannot write $x=2\!\iff\! x^2=4$, because $(-2)^2=4$ while $-2\neq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot assume that a root/solution always exists, especially when sqrt is present. At first test with a few values of $x$ to ascertain whether  it can be satisfied approximately. The squaring sometimes introduces possibility of the second sign before the radical.

The equation as you gave ( positive value for both sqrts) has no real solution as x must be > 7.

However, $$ -\sqrt{x-7} + \sqrt{x-4} = 1 $$ has the solution $ x = 8. $